# arXiv preprint and final paper differing by sections and appendices

Tags: publications, citations, preprint, arxiv

Because of the style of a journal, and the space limit, I was asked to remove a section and all appendices.

While I have no problem with that, I want to preserve it in the arXiv preprint.

So:

- Is it OK to have different final papers and its arXiv version? 
  (perhaps with the comment, e.g. *"Sec 3.4. and Appendices A and B only in the arXiv version"*)
- Is it OK to cite in a paper its own arXiv version? 
  (e.g. *derivation of (15) is in [5]*?)

Comment: One problem that can come from situations like this is ambiguity when people reference specific locations in your paper: if I cite “Migdal 2012, §3.2” does §3.2 mean the same thing in the arXiv version as in the journal version?  To some extent this can be avoided by careful arrangement of the material — e.g. if a section is omitted from the middle, that’ll change the numbering of later sections, but if what’s omitted is the second half of a section, that won’t affect anything else.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There doesn't need to be a strict correlation between an arXiv publication and an actual publication. It's actually common to use arXiv to publish extended/longer version of a published version (which seems exactly what you want to do). So

- Yes, it's OK to have a final paper that differs from the arXiv version.
- Yes, it's even encouraged to cite the arXiv version to point to appendices/extra material/proofs/detailed examples, etc.

However, the main rule is still that your journal paper must be self-contained, i.e., must be understandable without having to read the arXiv version. In other words, if removing the section implies to remove a definition (for instance), then you must put this definition somewhere else in the paper.

Comment: The other crucial thing is that the arXiv version should make it absolutely clear what does or doesn't appear in the published version.  (For example, by explaining this in the introduction and briefly at the beginning of each arXiv-only section.)  Otherwise, it can lead to serious confusion when people refer to the paper without realizing there are multiple versions.

Comment: You also need to be careful of running afoul of what is considered allowed and not allowed with respect to published manuscripts. Some journals allow you to do whatever you like, so long as you don't use _their_ version to do it. Others don't permit archiving elsewhere.

Comment: Well, you're certainly _not allowed_ to use arXiv's `Journal-ref` if the two things are not identical in contents!